# Using the Stanford Dependency Parser on a previously tagged sentence

Tags: java, twitter, nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I'm currently using the Twitter POS tagger [available here](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/) to tag out tweets into the Penn-Tree Bank tags.

Here is that code:

```
import java.util.List;

import cmu.arktweetnlp.Tagger;
import cmu.arktweetnlp.Tagger.TaggedToken;

/* Tags the tweet text */
List<TaggedToken> tagTweet(String text) throws IOException {

    // Loads Penn Treebank POS tags
    tagger.loadModel("res/model.ritter_ptb_alldata_fixed.txt");

    // Tags the tweet text
    taggedTokens = tagger.tokenizeAndTag(text);

    return taggedTokens;
}
```

Now I need to identify where the direct objects are in these tags.  After some searching, I've discovered that the Stanford Parser can do this, by way of the Stanford Typed Dependencies, ([online example](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)).  By using the dobj() call, I should be able to get what I need.

However, I have not found any good documentation about how to feed already-tagged sentences into this tool.  From what I understand, before using the Dependency Parser I need to create a tree from the sentence's tokens/tags. How is this done? I have not been able to find any example code.

The Twitter POS Tagger contains an instance of the Stanford NLP Tools, so I'm not far off, however I am not familiar enough with the Stanford tools to feed my POS-tagged text into it in order to get the dependency parser to work properly.  [The FAQ does mention this functionality](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f), but without any example code to go off of, I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it is done with completely manual creation of the `List` discussed in [the FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/parser-faq.shtml#f):

```
String[] sent3 = { "It", "can", "can", "it", "." };
// Parser gets second "can" wrong without help (parsing it as modal MD)
String[] tag3 = { "PRP", "MD", "VB", "PRP", "." };                                                 
List<TaggedWord> sentence3 = new ArrayList<TaggedWord>();
for (int i = 0; i < sent3.length; i++) {
  sentence3.add(new TaggedWord(sent3[i], tag3[i]));
}
Tree parse = lp.parse(sentence3);
parse.pennPrint();
```